# protected memory calling properly, string/bytes variable visibility with a memory dump

Tags: c#, memory

I need to clear my vision of protected memory and how to use it properly.

Pratically all samples on the web are similar to this:

```
byte[] sensitiveData = new byte[]
{
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
    0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10
};

Console.WriteLine("Before protection:");
PrintBytes(sensitiveData); // utility function that simply prints out the byte array -- not part of the framework

ProtectedMemory.Protect(sensitiveData, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);

Console.WriteLine("After protection:");
PrintBytes(sensitiveData);

ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(sensitiveData, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);

Console.WriteLine("After unprotection:");
PrintBytes(sensitiveData)

The output from this code is:

Before protection:
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0A
0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F, 10
After protection:
16, 9A, B1, A7, 3E, 09, 1B, 5F, FF, 30
B7, 64, 90, 4B, 15, FC
After unprotection:
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0A
0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 0F, 10
```

My question is very simple: Why i need to declare a variable containing the data to protect before to protect it?
In the sample i mean this:

```
byte[] sensitiveData = new byte[]
{
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
    0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10
};
```

I don't know how hackers intercept memory but i suppose a filled variable is in a clear and unsafe state in memory, somewhere!

It's not better/possible to protect it directly:

```
ProtectedMemory.Protect(new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 }, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);
```

If yes, please should you explain me how? Thanks a lot!

If elsewhere it's not possible/it's the same thing or so please should you explain why we are talking about security where a variable is declared and filled with sensitive data? There is a better way to protect memory/variables?

Thanks for your patience and sry for all that questions...

Comment: Because in order for that to be useful, there need to be some values stored in memory, that you can reference. What would you call `PrintBytes` on in your "directly"  example?

Comment: I mean to use ProtectedMemory.Protect(sensitiveData, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess); and ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(sensitiveData, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess); as variables itself... or better the first as variable(container), the second as result.. but both encryped at the starting point...

Comment: RAM is backed by the operating system paging file.  An attacker can find it back in this file years after the machine is discarded.  You have a lot more exposure with this code, it is also present in the executable file from the byte[] initializer.  So actually protecting it dynamically like this is not very useful.  Which goes to show that there's no true substitute for physical security.  A lock door and a shredder.

Comment: It's interesting that Protected Memory should be filled with a stream..... a stream of Bytes[] ...... another resource use the same method: Encryption... Well, can I write an encrypted file direct into protected memory? Or better can I call the ProtectedMemory passing the output stream of an encrypted file as first value?

Comment: @Alex, thanks now i understand... what i'm searching for already exist and it's called Encryption... i can start with encrypted data (a file or memory string) but somewhere and sometime i need to use that data and i need an unencrypted var .... lol i'm stupid, sorry to all and thanks for the help!